# What's the difference between DtoD and PtoP memory copies?

Tags: cuda, terminology, acronym, nvvp

While profiling application with nvprof I found both `PtoP` and `DtoD` memcpy. I am not sure about the difference between these two.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

**Device to device (DtoD)** is a copy within a single GPU. 
**Peer to Peer (PtoP)** is from one GPU to another.

The latter only happens in multi-GPU systems.

And for other transfers host refers to CPU, device refers to GPU.

The naming device to device transfer predates a lot of the work on multiple GPUs, otherwise the naming might have been a little different.

Comment: I ran the application in a multi-GPU system. I found that the DtoD copy has a BW utilization of ~80 GB/s while PtoP copy needed 4 GB/s in a system with PCIe interconnect. Hence, the DtoD copy has to be within the same device.